ChromeCast add tag <script> for dpad controls
I am using "ChromeCast HD". When loading the cast receiver I see an extra tag <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework_controls_dpad_tv.js">‹/script>
in my html.
I did not add this tag. I think the device is proxying the content and added this tag itself.
I also have a TV box with built-in Chromecast and the <script> is not added to the TV box.
How can I block the <script> from being added to my html?
Maybe it exists some 'CastReceiverOptions' that iI can use when Google Cast are starting?
enter image description here
enter image description here

you could try setting a CSP

@DanielA.White I am using <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js"></script>. It also requests external resources. If I use CSP, cast_receiver_framework.js will not work.

Have you considered that it’s that script adding the other one?
